# Find a word and replace it?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to find one word thoughout a whole webpage or website and replace it for another word. For example I wanted to find all the instances of the word California and replace it with Nevada.

I am using dreamweaver

Thanks

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Your answer is most likeley your first hit in Google when you search for "Find and replace Dreamweaver" ..

Comment: I have read tutorials for dreamweaver and front page as well as googling. with no joy. I thought the question made it obvious where I was stuck... :\

Comment: Please do. I have no idea how the first hit in Google does not answer this question: http://webdesign.about.com/od/dreamweaverhowtos/ht/dw_find_replace.htm

Comment: "_you're_ all dicks".  Edits for comments, when?!

Comment: @steveLaurs bit of an overreaction

Answer (score 3):

Dreamweaver includes find/replace as a utility within its test suite.  As a standard, I'd like to invite you to read the following informative and helpful document which shows just how to use this uncanny utility.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/dreamweaverhowtos/ht/dw_find_replace.htm

It's a fantastic read!  Oh and I must say with utter delight that while I'm not astute with Adobe Products as much as others, I *do* suspect using CTRL+F or CTRL+SHIFT+F, or something like CTRL+SHIFT+F+S may be helpful.  You may also find yourself using the command key instead of CTRL on the Macintosh to conjure the same results.

Comment: +1 just for 'uncanny'

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what I'd do without it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> shortcut and read instructions or just try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to popup the search window